# AlertDialog Builder: add event on click outside the dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I add an alert dialog with the response of a HttpURLConnection after a scan with camera.

I set the positive button called "SCANSIONA" with a call to the function "scanNow()" to come back to camera and set the             builder.setCancelable(false).

But to not obliged the user to click exactly to that button I thought to add the same function to the event "onCancel".

But it doesn't work, the dialog disappear but no event is fired.

I tried with "builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)" and "dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)" but both cases I receive the error "cannot resolve method".

What's wrong?
Here the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
//            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Voto registrato!");
            builder.setMessage(result.toString());
            builder.setPositiveButton("SCANSIONA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                        dialog.dismiss();
                    scanNow();
                }
            });
//            builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        builder.show();
        builder.setOnCancelListener(
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        //            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                       scanNow();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: cut builder.show(); and paste after  builder.setOnCancelListener({});

Comment: I feel a bit dummy :)
Thanks a lot!